# limit of outer measure equal with outer measure of union sets

Tags: measure-theory

I'm proving the statement.

> Let $\{ A_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be sequence of any sets. Let $m^{*}(A_{k})<\infty$ for all $k$. Prove that if $A_{1} \subset A_{2} \subset \cdots$, then 
>   $$
> \lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} m^{*}\left(A_{k}\right)=m^{*}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}\right),
> $$
>   where $m^*$ is a outer measure.

I proved $\geq$. But I'm doubtful about my proof of $\leq$. Here is my claim:

> we prove that $\lim _{k \rightarrow \infty} m^{*}\left(A_{k}\right)\leq m^{*}\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}\right).$ Choose $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)\leq m^{*}(A_{k_0})$. Then, we see that
>   $$
> \lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)\leq m^{*}(A_{k_0})\leq m^{*}(A_1 \cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_{k_0} \cup \cdots)=m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\right).
> $$

In addition, here is outer measure's definition:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R} .$ Let $\mathcal{I}=\left\{I_{k} | k \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ be a countable collection of open (closed, semiopen) intervals with $A \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} I_{k} .$ We define an **outer measure** of $A,$ denoted by $m^{*}(A)$ as
$$
m^{*}(A):=\inf _{\mathcal{I}} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} l\left(I_{k}\right).
$$

Thanks:)

Comment: $(m(A_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ is a non-decreasing sequence, why are you allowed to take $k_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow +\infty}m^*(A_k)\leqslant m^*(A_{k_0})$ ? If you just state that $$\forall k\in\mathbb{N}^*,A_k\subset\bigcup_{p\geqslant 1}A_p$$ It's finished.

Comment: As you state, by monotonicity of outer measure, we see
$$m^{*}(A_k) \leq m^{*}(\bigcup_{p\geq 1}A_p) .$$
But, thing is, I can't determine relationship between  $\lim_{k \to \infty} m^{*}(A_k)$ and $m^{*}(A_k)$.

Comment: If $(m^*(A_k))_{k\in\mathbb{N}^*}$ is non-decreasing then for all $k_0\in\mathbb{N}^*$, $m^*(A_{k_0})\leqslant\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow +\infty}m^*(A_k)$. And if $$ \forall k\in\mathbb{N}^*,m^*(A_k)\leqslant m^*\left(\bigcup_{p\geqslant 1}A_p\right)$$Taking the limit when $k\rightarrow +\infty$ gives you the wanted inequality.

Comment: Oh! I can understand clearly! Thanks!